# How to extract the string data from the fql query

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

Really a beginner question.

The following code queries the facebook friends as I understand. How do I get the first name and last name of all my friends as a string so I can put it in a list box?

Thank you

```
private async void FqlAsyncExample()
{
        try
        {
            // query to get all the friends
            var query = string.Format("SELECT uid,pic_square,first_name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1={0})", "me()");

            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.q = query;
            dynamic result = await _fb.GetTaskAsync("fql", parameters);

            TotalFriends.Text = string.Format("You have {0} friend(s).", result.data.Count);
        }
        catch (FacebookApiException ex)
        {
            // handle error message
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The data type fo result.data is IEnumerable.  Your best bet is to do something like this.

```
dynamic friends = result.data;
foreach(var friend in friends)
{
    Console.WriteLine(friend.first_name);
}
```

This will output the first name for each of your friends to the console.  Since you are using a dynamic object, whatever you put after the . needs to be the exact name of the JSON key field.  In your case the options will be

```
friend.uid
friend.pic_square
friend.first_name
```

These will all be easily casted to the type of string (which is what they actually are), however uid can also be cast to long.

In order to get the last name of all your friends, you have to modify your FQL to something like this:

```
SELECT uid,pic_square,first_name,last_name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
```

Since you left out "last_name" in your original query.

Comment: @AvishayRebibo please be sure to mark this as an answer to your question, otherwise it remains an unanswered question.